# Deleting and inserting data into database using spring data JPA with transaction support

Tags: java, spring

I have below method where I am doing below operation but getting duplicate entry exception

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public ResponseVo crudOperation(CRUDVo curdVO) {
    Customer customer = repo.getDetails(curdVO.getStoreCode());

    List<Customer> customers = repo.getDetailsById(curdVO.getId());
    repo.delete(customers);

    insertCustomer(curdVO);
}

private void insertCustomer(CRUDVo curdVO) {
    Customer customer;

    for (Short programId : storeVO.getPrograms()) {
        customer = new Customer();          
        customer.setAddress(address);
        customer.setProgram(programId );
        customer.setMobile(curdVO.getMobile());
        repo.save(customer);
    }
}
```

If I am not using   `@Transactional` annotation then above working fine because on executing `repo.delete(customers)` this its deleting data from database. But in case of transaction its releasing data after completion of the transaction. Due to this reason I am getting below exception

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry
```

Stacktrace ::

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '3-4727' for key 'UNQ_KEY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 153 common frames omitted
```

Please suggest why data is not deleting after executing repo.delete(customers) statement

Comment: How is the primary key of the Customer generatead?

Comment: Its autoincremented

Comment: can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Please check my updated question

Comment: and how's UNQ_KEY defined?

Comment: using customer mobile no

Comment: and where do you set this?

Comment: What if you call `repo.flush();` after 'repo.delete(customers);` ?

Comment: Could you attach your model definition (@entities)?